# Accept POST request in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

My react-router is version 4.2.0

I'm trying to accept a POST request to my React application.  I may be blind, but I'm unable to find a way to specify a request method (GET, POST) on my routes.

How can I set this up to accept POST requests?

```
render((
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" history={history} render={() => (
            loggedIn() 
                ? (<MyApp />)
                : (<Redirect to="/login"/>)
        )}/>
        <Route exact path="/login" history={history}  render={() => (
            loggedIn() 
                ? (<Redirect to="/"/>)
                : (<Login />)
        )}/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Ideally, I would like to have a 3rd route that accepts a POST request to process the POST from a vendor.

I found [express-react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-react-router) but was unable to locate/install the "express-location" package.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is client side routing. You cannot post request here.
You need to listen to post requests on your express js server.

In your serverjs:

```
app.post('/',function(req,res){
 res.send("hello")
})
```

That would do the trick.

Comment: I knew that I could do it in my API, but I was hoping to do it directly in the react. 

Accepting because if there's no way to do it, then there's no way to do it.

Thanks